# nginx serving 404 pages

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, laravel-5.1

EDIT: Based on @Devons advice I ran the following commands with no errors ([found in this post](https://superuser.com/questions/91935/how-to-chmod-all-directories-except-files-recursively)):

```
$ sudo find /var/public/www -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +

$ sudo find /var/public/www -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

But when I list the files inside www the permissions still look wrong. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   4096 Aug 28 12:45 app
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   1646 Aug 28 12:45 artisan
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf      0 Aug 28 12:45 bootstrap
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   1201 Aug 28 12:45 composer.json
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 105046 Aug 28 12:55 composer.lock
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   4096 Aug 28 12:45 config
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf      0 Aug 28 12:45 database
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    503 Aug 28 12:45 gulpfile.js
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    159 Aug 28 12:45 package.json
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     87 Aug 28 12:45 phpspec.yml
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    899 Aug 28 12:45 phpunit.xml
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf      0 Aug 28 12:45 public
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   1928 Aug 28 12:45 readme.md
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf      0 Aug 28 12:45 resources
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    567 Aug 28 12:45 server.php
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf      0 Aug 28 12:45 storage
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf      0 Aug 28 12:45 tests
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   4096 Aug 28 12:56 vendor
```

---

This is my first time with nginx and cannot get laravel welcome page to show. I am using ubuntu 14.04 and VBox 5.

I have my server configured in `/var/nginx/sites-enabled/default` as

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    charset utf-8;
    server_name doimain.app www.domain.app;

    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Inside `/var/www/public` I can list the laravel public folder files

```
$ ls -l /var/www/public
total 3
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 Aug 28 12:45 favicon.ico
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 1786 Aug 28 12:45 index.php
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   24 Aug 28 12:45 robots.txt
```

But I get 404 when I go to `domain.app`. The nginx error log shows:

```
2015/08/28 14:29:35 [crit] 1487#0: *14 stat() "/var/www/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.0.18, server: domain.app, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.app"
```

I have tried without success the following:

Ensure www-data owns the folder structure `/var/www`

```
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Changed access rights to `/var/www`

```
$ sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public directory is owned by root and is not readable to others.  You either need to change the ownership to www-data or chmod **all** of the folder and files.  The folder should be 0755 and files be 0644 for most configurations.  You can leave it how you have it if the files are owned by the same user running nginx and php (I assume www-data).

Changing the ownership of /var/www by itself does nothing, you have to change all the folders and files in the web directory.

You can chmod and chown recursively with the `-R` flag.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/public
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that www-data should, generally speaking, not own much at all in a website directory, by doing so you open yourself up to code exploits as you allow www-data (Apache) to write to any file, allow permissions with chmod where required, don't allow it to everything! See this AskUbuntu answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777

Comment: @williamvicary, I don't know how relevant that is since you'd need a server side language to perform the write.  Apache alone can't do anything.  It's fairly normal to have the PHP process owned by the same user that owns the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by addig `www-data` user to `vboxsf` group and restarting the server.

```
$sudo usermod -G vboxsf -a www-data
```